# Keepalive server side?

Tags: c, server, tcp, embedded, lwip

I'm currently working on an embedded TCP server using LWIP stack. I would like to use the keepalive functions in the server to let him detect when a client unexpectedly lost the connection. Do you know if keepalive can be used from the server or does-it only concern client side ?

thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Using LwIP's BSD-like sockets API and the setsockopt() call you can keep it alive.